# PHP fetch 3d array

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array and i want to fetch `[2] => Array` with `foreach` but it's showing me an error.

for example array name is `$other`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaaaaaaaaaaa
            [1] => bbbbbbbbbbbb
            [2] => cccccccccccc
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dddddddddddd
            [1] => eeeeeeeeeeee
            [2] => ffffffffffff
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => gggggggggggg
            [1] => hhhhhhhhhhhh
            [2] => iiiiiiiiiiii
        )                
)
```

fetch array:

```
foreach ($other[2] as $value) {
    echo $value.'<br/>';
}
```

How do I print all the values of the second array?

Comment: seems, your code looking fine. Wat is the error you have had?

Comment: This code should work. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @KrishR. i do not get an error. this foreach only fetch two row of array

Comment: And what do you need? every second element of each array?

Comment: @u_mulder in this array i have more than 20 rows

Comment: THis is not an answer to my question. Please edit your question and provide the result of what you need.

Comment: The array in the question is 2D, not 3D.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest further more

```
foreach ($other as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
       if($k==2)
        {
        echo $v.'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
cccccccccccc
ffffffffffff
iiiiiiiiiiii
```

Comment: this is only fetch 2 row of array.

Comment: Posting your expected output makes things go easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this,

```
    <?php 
    $x = array
    (
        0 => array
            (
                0 => 'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
                1 => 'bbbbbbbbbbbb',
                2 => 'cccccccccccc'
            ),
        1 => array
            (
                0 => 'dddddddddddd',
                1 => 'eeeeeeeeeeee',
                2 => 'ffffffffffff'
            ),
        2 => array
            (
                0 => 'gggggggggggg',
                1 => 'hhhhhhhhhhhh',
                2 => 'iiiiiiiiiiii'
            )                
    );


    $count = count($x);

    $w = $count - 1;

    var_dump($x[$w]);

    ?>
```